# How do I prove that $|V| \geq |F|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**Question**

$F$ is a field and $({}\cdot{}, {}+{}, V)$ is a vector space over $F$. Suppose $V \neq \{0\}$. How do I prove that $|V| \geq |F|$?

**Attempt**

I know that $|V| \geq |F|$ is true if and only if exists a single-valued function $f: F \to V$. But I don't know how to proceed from here (or if this helps with the proof).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a nonzero vector $\mathbf{v} \in V$ and consider the embedding of your field $F$ in $V$ as scalar multiples of it:
\begin{align} 
\varphi: F &\to V \\
c &\mapsto c\mathbf{v}
\end{align}

Vector space axioms guarantee that this is well-defined (all those scalar multiples do in fact live in $V$). Why is the function $\varphi$ necessarily injective? Try to prove it yourself, and click to reveal the spoiler if you get stuck.

> Suppose that $\varphi(c_1) = \varphi(c_2) \in V$, so $c_1\mathbf{v} = c_2\mathbf{v}$. Subtracting and factoring, we get $(c_1 - c_2)\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$. But since $\mathbf{v} \neq \mathbf{0}$, we must have $c_1 - c_2 = 0 \in F$, i.e. $c_1 = c_2$.